# mysql - how to use a json array inside an IN

Tags: mysql, arrays, json

I have a table with a `JSON` column called `related`. I'm using this to store and array, and now I'd like to use this array inside an `IN`. How can I do this?

e.g. `SELECT * FROM products WHERE id IN (select related FROM products WHERE id = 1);`

and `SELECT related FROM products` returns `[1,2,3]`

Comment: I think this may indicate a basic database design error.

Comment: create a custom function returning a table. with as input that json field. Subsequently use it in your where.

Comment: what is the column data type of related in the products table?

Comment: @Simulant `JSON`

Answer (score 0):

You can use function

UPDATE 2: (tested):

```
SELECT
`id`,
`related`
 FROM
`products`
 WHERE
    JSON_SEARCH((SELECT `related` FROM `products` WHERE `id` = 4) ,'one', `id`)
             IS NOT NULL;
```

see this (updated): https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5ESH1X9qjB46GAzG6DkdfJ/1

See also:

https://benjaminlistwon.com/blog/working-with-json-data-in-mysql-part-1-of-3/

Comment: invalid data type for JSON data in argument 2... a JSON string or JSON type is required.

Comment: check out the new SQL fiddle i made. That will show the above function will work.

Comment: i think you're missing what I want to do - that is to get all data from the products table where the id is contained in the json column of one row. e.g. get all data for related where id = 1

Comment: i see what you mean. I've updated the fiddle and code. Seems to be exactly what you need.